# Compress Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I need to compress a table. I used `alter table tablename compress` to compress the table. After doing this the table size remained the same.

How should I be compressing the table?

Answer (score 6):

To compress the old blocks of the table use:

```
alter table table_name move compress;
```

This will reinsert the records in another blocks, compressed, and discard old blocks, so you'll gain space. And invalidates the indexex, so you will need to rebuild them.

Answer (score -1):

Compress does not affect already stored rows. Please, check the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables002.htm#CJAGFBFG):

> " You specify table compression with the COMPRESS clause of
>   the CREATE TABLE statement. You can enable compression for an existing
>   table by using this clause in an ALTER TABLEstatement. In this case,
>   the only data that is compressed is the data inserted or updated after
>   compression is enabled..."

ALTER TABLE t MOVE COMPRESS is a valid answer. But if you use different non default options, especially with big data volume, do regression tests before using ALTER TABLE ... MOVE. 
There were historically more problems (performance degradations and bugs) with it. If you have access, look Oracle bug database to see if there are known problems for features and version you use.) 
You are on safer side if you:

- create new table

  insert data from original (old) table

  drop old table

  rename new table to old table name

Comment: A _link_ to the official documentation and a quote from it that indicates what you have written is true would make this answer better; this is more of a comment. As it stands your answer is hearsay, you have no proof of what you are saying and no suggestion to actually _answer_ the question.

Comment: I downvoted for the reasons stated. This doesn't answer the question. I wouldn't have downvoted if you had answered the question but I wouldn't have upvoted either as I believe this would be a poor answer that would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: This is the reason he didn't see effect of the command.He needs to find more details. As further actions would depend on more details in his context...

Comment: I didn't donwvoted you, but you should see the question of the user: "How should I be compressing the table?". Explaining the reason why his command has no effect is good, but he ask how to compress.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have just added one more point about it.